# Converting from a ForEach loop to a Parallel.ForEach loop when summarizing into a double slows things down

Tags: c#, thread-safety, parallel.foreach

I have a section of C# code as follows.  This code summarizes a column of 'doubles' in a DataTable :

```
var data = this.Db.ExecuteRead(query, this.Score.Name);
var time = 0.0;
foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
{
    time += this.ParseDouble(row[0].ToString()) / MillisecondsPerMinute;
}
```

This code takes 4 seconds to execute.  I wanted to speed it up, so I parallelized it as follows:

```
Parallel.ForEach(
                data.AsEnumerable(),
                row =>
                    {
                        time += this.ParseDouble(row[0].ToString()) / MillisecondsPerMinute;
                    });
```

This code takes 3 seconds to execute.  It also causes collisions.  I don't think a 'double' thread safe.  This was expected.  I then added a Mutex to make it thread safe:

```
Parallel.ForEach(
                data.AsEnumerable(),
                row =>
                    {
                        mut.WaitOne();
                        ptime += this.ParseDouble(row[0].ToString()) / MillisecondsPerMinute;
                        mut.ReleaseMutex();
                    });
```

This code is much slower.  It takes 15 seconds to execute but produces accurate results.  My question is, am I better off staying with the standard 'ForEach' here, or can I implement the multithreading in a better way?

For reference, here is the ParseDouble method:

```
protected double ParseDouble(string text)
{
    double value;
    if (!double.TryParse(text, out value))
    {
        throw new DoubleExpectedException();
    }

    return value;
}
```

Comment: Not every problem is possible to be solved faster by parallel/concurrent solutions. Here it depends on what is taking up the most time. First start with checking how long `var data = Db.ExecuteRead(query, Score.Name).ToList();` takes. If that is slow then optimizing the processing won't solve much. Then for something like this it's better to partition the problem, calculate the values for chunks of your data. Then after you're done combine all the chunk results (should be quick and easy). There is a `Parallel.ForEach` overload that takes a `Partitioner` to help with this.

Comment: Could you include in the question the `ParseDouble` method? Also how many rows has the `DataTable`?

Comment: *"It also causes collisions."* <== Could you elaborate on that? Do you mean that the `double time` variable does not have the correct value in the end?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias  In regards to collisions:  When I don't use the Mutex, `double time` is always different and always a lower value than it should be.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I have added the ParseDouble method to the question.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias In regards to your question of "How many rows".  =>  millions.

Comment: use for loop, it is faster than foreach

Answer (score 2):

Here are some approaches. First a simple `Parallel.ForEach`, reducing the protected region ([`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement)) to the absolute minimum required (the updating of the shared state). This should minimize the contention for the lock.

```
DataTable data = this.Db.ExecuteRead(query, this.Score.Name);
double totalTime = 0.0;
Parallel.ForEach(data.AsEnumerable(), row =>
{
    double time = Double.Parse(row[0].ToString()) / MillisecondsPerMinute;
    lock (data) { totalTime += time; }
});
```

A [PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq) approach. Easy and secure, but probably not the most efficient:

```
double totalTime = data
    .AsEnumerable()
    .AsParallel()
    .Select(row => Double.Parse(row[0].ToString()) / MillisecondsPerMinute)
    .Sum();
```

The combination of `Parallel.ForEach` and [`Partitioner.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner.create) should give the best performance, because it allows to chunkify the workload:

```
double totalTime = 0.0;
Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0, data.Rows.Count), () => 0.0D,
    (range, state, accumulator) =>
{
    for (int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
    {
        DataRow row = data.Rows[i];
        accumulator += Double.Parse(row[0].ToString()) / MillisecondsPerMinute;
    }
    return accumulator;
}, accumulator =>
{
    lock (data) { totalTime += accumulator; }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not always preferable. For fast loop bodies, Parallel.ForEach can degrade performance.
One more thing is that if your iteration items are not dependent on your previous item then go ahead use it but if they are dependent on each other then I would suggest using Regular foreach.